# I want to align the content of the main nav menu in the center

Tags: html, css

I want to align the content of the main nav in the center as the sub nav.

I have tried implementing 'text-align=center' still no help. First it was in the center, but to stretch the sub nav background to 100% like the main nav background I had to add 'width=100%' to 'navigation-center' which solved the problem for the background of sub nav but aligned its main nav content to the left.

Here is the html:

```
<header>

<!-- ======================== Navigation ======================== -->
<div class="container">

    <!-- === Navigation-Top (SOCIAL & TEL) === -->
    <nav class="navigation-top clearfix">

        <!-- Navigation-Top-Left -->
        <div class="navigation-top-left">
            <a class="box" href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
                    </a>
            <a class="box" href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
                    </a>
            <a class="box" href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>
                    </a>
        </div>
        <!--/ Navigation-Top-Left End -->

        <!-- Navigation-Top-Right -->
        <div class="navigation-top-right">
            <a class="box" href="#">
                        <i class="icon icon-phone-handset"></i> +91 - 22 - 2831 4011
                    </a>
        </div>
        <!--/ Navigation-Top-Right End -->

    </nav>
    <!-- /=== Navigation-Top (SOCIAL & TEL) End === -->

    <!-- === Navigation-Main (LOGO) === -->
    <nav class="navigation-main clearfix">


        <!-- Logo -->
        <div class="logo animated fadeIn">
            <a href="index.html">
                        <img class="logo-desktop" src="assets/images/logo.png" alt="Alternate Text" />
                        <img class="logo-mobile center-block" src="assets/images/logo-mobile.png" alt="Alternate Text"/>
                    </a>
        </div>
        <!--/ Logo End -->

    </nav>
    <!--/ === Navigation-Main (LOGO) End === -->

</div>
<!--/ Container End -->

<!-- === Navigation-Main (MENU) === -->
<nav class="navigation-main clearfix">

    <!-- Toggle-Menu Mobile/Tablet -->
    <div class="target-burger"><i class="icon icon-menu"></i></div>
    <!--/ Toggle-Menu Mobile/Tablet End -->

    <div id="overlay">

        <!-- Navigation-Block -->
        <div class="navigation-block main-nav navigation-block-megamenu clearfix">

            <ul class="navigation-center">
                <li>
                    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">About Us <span class="open-dropdown"><i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></span></a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li><a href="about-introduction.html">Introduction</a></li>
                        <li><a href="about-story.html">Our Story</a></li>
                        <li><a href="about-philosophy.html">Our Philosophy</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="food-beverages.html">Food & Beverages</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="menu-offerings.html">Menu Offerings</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Events <span class="open-dropdown"><i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></span></a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li><a href="about-introduction.html">Private Events</a></li>
                        <li><a href="about-story.html">Corporate Events</a></li>
                        <li><a href="about-philosophy.html">Weddings</a></li>
                        <li><a href="about-story.html">Major Events</a></li>
                        <li><a href="about-philosophy.html">Destination Events</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </div>
        <!--/ Navigation-Block End -->

    </div>

</nav>


<!--/ === Navigation-Main (MENU) End === -->
```

Here is the css:

```
 nav.navigation-top {
     display: none;
     margin-top: 5px;
     margin-bottom: 5px;
     -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
     -o-transition: all 0.5s;
     -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
     transition: all 0.5s;
 }
 @media (max-width: 992px) {
     nav.navigation-top-mob-nav {
         display: block;
         padding: 10px 0;
         margin-top: 5px;
         margin-bottom: 5px;
         -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
         -o-transition: all 0.5s;
         -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
         transition: all 0.5s;
    }
     nav.navigation-top-mob-nav > div {
         position: relative;
         bottom: 10px;
    }
     nav.navigation-top-mob-nav .navigation-top-left {
         float: left;
         padding-left: 15px;
    }
     nav.navigation-top-mob-nav .navigation-top-left .box {
         padding-right: 13.33333px;
    }
     nav.navigation-top-mob-nav .navigation-top-right {
         float: right;
         padding-right: 15px;
         pointer-events: all;
    }
     nav.navigation-top-mob-nav .navigation-top-right .box {
         padding-left: 13.33333px;
    }
     nav.navigation-top-mob-nav .box {
         color: white;
         display: inline-block;
         font-size: 11px;
         text-transform: uppercase;
    }
     nav.navigation-top-mob-nav .box .icon {
         font-size: 85%;
         vertical-align: middle;
    }
}
 @media (min-width: 992px) {
     nav.navigation-top {
         display: block;
         padding: 20px 0;
    }
     nav.navigation-top .navigation-top-left {
         float: left;
    }
     nav.navigation-top .navigation-top-left .box {
         padding-right: 13.33333px;
    }
     nav.navigation-top .navigation-top-right {
         float: right;
         pointer-events: none;
    }
     nav.navigation-top .navigation-top-right .box {
         padding-left: 13.33333px;
    }
}
 nav.navigation-top .box {
     color: white;
     display: inline-block;
     font-size: 11px;
     text-transform: uppercase;
}
 nav.navigation-top .box .icon {
     font-size: 85%;
     vertical-align: middle;
}
 nav.navigation-main {
     position: relative;
}
 nav.navigation-main .logo {
     height: 65px;
     -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
     -o-transition: all 0.5s;
     -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
     transition: all 0.5s;
}
 nav.navigation-main .logo .logo-desktop {
     display: none;
}
 @media (min-width: 992px) {
     nav.navigation-main .logo .logo-desktop {
         display: inline-block !important;
    }
     nav.navigation-main .logo .logo-mobile {
         display: none;
    }
     nav.navigation-main .logo > a {
         text-align: center;
    }
     nav.navigation-main .logo img {
         width: 100%;
         margin: 0 auto;
    }
}
 nav.navigation-main .logo > a {
     display: block;
}
 nav.navigation-main .toggle-menu {
     height: 85px;
     position: absolute;
     right: 0;
     top: -85px;
     font-size: 27px;
     padding: 24.5px 20px;
     line-height: 36px;
     color: white;
}
 nav.navigation-main .toggle-menu .icon {
     display: block;
     -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
     -o-transition: all 0.5s;
     -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
     transition: all 0.5s;
}
 nav.navigation-main .toggle-menu .icon:before {
     display: inline-block;
}
 nav.navigation-main .toggle-menu.open .icon {
     -moz-transform: scale(0.8) rotate(180deg);
     -ms-transform: scale(0.8) rotate(180deg);
     -o-transform: scale(0.8) rotate(180deg);
     -webkit-transform: scale(0.8) rotate(180deg);
     transform: scale(0.8) rotate(180deg);
}
 nav.navigation-main .toggle-menu.open .icon:before {
     content: "\e870" !important;
}
 nav.navigation-main .navigation-block ul {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
}
 nav.navigation-main .navigation-block ul li {
     list-style-type: none;
}
 nav.navigation-main .navigation-block ul li a {
     display: block;
     margin-left: 15px;
     margin-right: 15px;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     font-family: 'Calibre-Light', normal;
     font-size: 12px;
     font-weight: 300;
}
 nav.navigation-main .navigation-block ul li > a {
     color: white;
}
 nav.navigation-main .navigation-block ul li:hover > a {
     color: #CBCBCB;
}
 nav.navigation-main .navigation-block ul li > ul {
     background-color: rgba(81, 85, 97, 0.1);
}
 nav.navigation-main .navigation-block ul li > ul li {
     display: inline-block;
}
 nav.navigation-main .navigation-block ul li > ul li a {
     display: block;
     margin-left: 15px;
     margin-right: 15px;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     font-family: 'Calibre-Light', normal;
     font-size: 12px;
     font-weight: 300;
}
 @media (min-width: 992px) {
     nav.navigation-main {
         position: relative;
         z-index: 999999;
    }
     nav.navigation-main .logo {
         -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
         -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
         -o-transform: translateX(-50%);
         -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
         transform: translateX(-50%);
         position: absolute;
         bottom: -50px;
         left: 50%;
         width: 250px;
         height: 113px;
         z-index: 9;
    }
     nav.navigation-main .logo img {
         width: 183px;
         height: 105px;
         -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
         -o-transition: all 0.5s;
         -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
         transition: all 0.5s;
    }
     nav.navigation-main .target-burger {
         display: none;
    }
     nav.navigation-main .navigation-block {
         display: block;
    }
     nav.navigation-main .navigation-block.navigation-block-megamenu {
         width: 100%;
         height: 50px;
         line-height: 50px;
         position: relative;
         text-align: center;
         margin: auto;
         padding: auto;
         background-image: url("../assets/images/nav-01.png");
         background-position: center;
         margin-top: 50px;
    }
     nav.navigation-main .navigation-block > ul > li {
         float: left;
         display: block;
    }
     nav.navigation-main .navigation-block > ul > li:first-child > a {
         padding-left: 0;
    }
     nav.navigation-main .navigation-block > ul > li:last-child > a {
         padding-right: 0;
    }
     nav.navigation-main .navigation-block > ul li > ul, nav.navigation-main .navigation-block.navigation-block-megamenu .mega-dropdown-content {
         filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0);
         opacity: 0;
         visibility: hidden;
         display: block;
         position: absolute;
         left: 0;
         height: 50px;
         line-height: 50px;
         -moz-transform: translateY(10px);
         -ms-transform: translateY(10px);
         -o-transform: translateY(10px);
         -webkit-transform: translateY(10px);
         transform: translateY(10px);
         -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
         -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
         box-shadow: 0 3px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    }
     nav.navigation-main .navigation-block.navigation-block-megamenu .mega-dropdown {
         position: initial;
    }
     nav.navigation-main .navigation-block.navigation-block-megamenu .mega-dropdown-content {
         background-image: url("../assets/images/main-nav-background.png");
         background-position: center;
         background-size: cover;
         color: white;
         left: 0;
         right: 0;
         width: 100%;
         height: 280px;
         padding: 3px;
    }
     nav.navigation-main .navigation-block.navigation-block-megamenu .mega-dropdown-content a {
         color: black;
         padding: 8px 0;
    }
     nav.navigation-main .navigation-block.navigation-block-megamenu .mega-dropdown-content .pre {
         padding-top: 25px;
         padding-bottom: 15px;
    }
     nav.navigation-main .navigation-block.navigation-block-megamenu .mega-dropdown-content img {
         width: 100%;
         max-width: 100%;
    }
     nav.navigation-main .navigation-block.navigation-block-megamenu .mega-dropdown-content .row > div {
         padding-left: 35px;
         padding-right: 35px;
    }
     nav.navigation-main .navigation-block.navigation-block-megamenu .mega-dropdown-content .title {
         font-family: 'TFArrowLight', cursive;
         font-weight: 500;
         text-transform: uppercase;
         margin-bottom: 10px;
         color: #ffffff;
    }
     nav.navigation-main .navigation-block.navigation-block-megamenu .mega-dropdown-content li:hover a {
         color: #ADADAD;
         -moz-transform: translateX(5px);
         -ms-transform: translateX(5px);
         -o-transform: translateX(5px);
         -webkit-transform: translateX(5px);
         transform: translateX(5px);
    }
     nav.navigation-main .navigation-block.navigation-block-megamenu .mega-dropdown-content li a {
         -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
         -o-transition: all 0.3s;
         -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
         transition: all 0.3s;
         font-weight: normal;
         color: #ffffff;
    }
     nav.navigation-main .navigation-block > ul li > ul li {
         background-color: none;
    }
     nav.navigation-main .navigation-block > ul li > ul li:hover a {
         color: #CBCBCB;
    }
     nav.navigation-main .navigation-block > ul li > ul li a {
         -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
         -o-transition: all 0.3s;
         -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
         transition: all 0.3s;
         font-weight: normal;
         background-color: none;
         color: #ffffff;
         text-align: center;
    }
     nav.navigation-main .navigation-block > ul li.hovered a {
    }
     nav.navigation-main .navigation-block > ul li.hovered > ul, nav.navigation-main .navigation-block > ul li.hovered .mega-dropdown-content {
         width: 100%;
         background-image: url("../assets/images/sub-nav-01.png");
         background-position: center;
         filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(enabled=false);
         opacity: 1;
         -moz-transition-property: opacity;
         -o-transition-property: opacity;
         -webkit-transition-property: opacity;
         transition-property: opacity;
         -moz-transition-duration: 0.33s;
         -o-transition-duration: 0.33s;
         -webkit-transition-duration: 0.33s;
         transition-duration: 0.33s;
         -moz-transform: translateY(0);
         -ms-transform: translateY(0);
         -o-transform: translateY(0);
         -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
         transform: translateY(0);
         overflow: hidden;
         visibility: visible;
         z-index: 1;
         text-align: center;
    }
     nav.navigation-main .navigation-block > ul.navigation-center {
         width: 100%;
         position: relative;
         float: none;
         display: inline-block;
         z-index: 999;
    }
     nav.navigation-main .navigation-block > ul.navigation-right {
         float: right;
    }
     nav.navigation-main .navigation-block > ul.navigation-right li > ul:after {
         left: auto;
         right: 20px;
    }
     nav.navigation-main .navigation-block > ul.navigation-right li {
         position: relative;
    }
     nav.navigation-main .navigation-block > ul.navigation-right li:nth-last-child(-n+2) ul {
         right: 0;
         left: auto;
    }
     nav.navigation-main .navigation-block ul li > ul li {
         border-top: 0px solid #dddddd;
    }
}
 @media (max-width: 991px) {
     nav.navigation-main .navigation-block {
         position: absolute;
         top: 100%;
         width: 100%;
         left: 0;
         z-index: 999;
         -moz-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
         -ms-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
         -o-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
         -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
         transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
         -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
         -o-transition: all 0.3s;
         -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
         transition: all 0.3s;
    }
     nav.navigation-main .navigation-block.toggled {
         background-color: #034A7D;
         -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
     nav.navigation-main .navigation-block ul li {
         border-top: 1px solid #006a9f;
    }
     nav.navigation-main .navigation-block ul li a {
         position: relative;
         font-size: 12px;
         color: #fff;
         padding: 1em 0;
         font-weight: 300;
         display: block;
         -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
         -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
         -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
         transition: all 0.5s ease;
    }
     nav.navigation-main .navigation-block ul li a .open-dropdown {
         position: absolute;
         display: block;
         width: 40px;
         height: 100%;
         right: 0;
         top: 0;
         font-size: 22px;
         line-height: 50px;
         text-align: center;
    }
     nav.navigation-main .navigation-block ul li a .open-dropdown i {
         -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
         -o-transition: all 0.3s;
         -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
         transition: all 0.3s;
    }
     nav.navigation-main .navigation-block.navigation-block-megamenu .mega-dropdown-content {
         padding: 10px;
         color: white;
    }
     nav.navigation-main .navigation-block ul li > ul, nav.navigation-main .navigation-block.navigation-block-megamenu .mega-dropdown-content {
         display: none;
    }
     nav.navigation-main .navigation-block.navigation-block-megamenu .mega-dropdown-content img {
         max-width: 100%;
    }
     nav.navigation-main .navigation-block.navigation-block-megamenu .mega-dropdown-content a {
         color: white;
         padding-left: 0;
         padding-right: 0;
    }
     nav.navigation-main .navigation-block.navigation-block-megamenu .mega-dropdown-content .row > div {
         padding-left: 15px;
         padding-right: 15px;
    }
     nav.navigation-main .navigation-block.navigation-block-megamenu .mega-dropdown-content .pre {
         padding: 15px 0;
    }
     nav.navigation-main .navigation-block.navigation-block-megamenu .mega-dropdown-content .title {
         color: white;
         font-size: 16px;
         margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
     nav.navigation-main .navigation-block.navigation-block-megamenu .mega-dropdown-content ul {
         margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
     nav.navigation-main .navigation-block.navigation-block-megamenu .expanded .mega-dropdown-content {
         display: block;
    }
     nav.navigation-main .navigation-block ul li > ul li {
         padding-left: 15px;
    }
     nav.navigation-main .navigation-block ul li.expanded > a {
         background-color: #002639;
    }
     nav.navigation-main .navigation-block ul li.expanded .open-dropdown i {
         -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
         -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
         -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
         -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
         transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
}
```

I want the content for the main nav in the center, please guide me along and let me know where I'm wrong. It will be a great help.

[Check the image here to check the current output which I'm getting right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dkGY.png)

Comment: This might help https://www.kirupa.com/html5/centering_vertically_horizontally.htm

Comment: Thanks Carol, ill check it once.

Comment: Thanks a ton Carol, It worked wonders, I just can't believe this.